# Runtime crash when updating an image at each frame in Qt/QML

Tags: c++, qt, crash, runtime-error, qml

The application is running fine and randomly crashes, the debugger is displaying this error :

> 0xc0000005: read access violation,
>
> QOpenGLFunctions_3_2_Compatibility::glBeginTransformFeedBack

but that doesn't help that much since I don't know where this function is used.

Through my tests I think that the problem is coming from the image display. The program retrieves raw data from a remote device connected to a camera and the application is displaying it to show the video in QML app. When I comment for example the source of the image in QML, it doesn't crash.

In a thread :

```
bool success;
DWORD bytesRead;
DWORD lastError;
const unsigned int imgSize = IMG_HEIGHT * IMG_WIDTH * 1;

_rawData = new uchar[imgSize];

while(!_abort)
{
    if(_namedPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        /* Get raw data from the pipe */
        success = ReadFile(
            _namedPipe,
            _rawData,
            imgSize,
            &bytesRead,
            NULL);

        if(success)
        {
            /* Build an image from the raw data and send it to the PipeVideoStreamPlayer */
            QImage clImage(_rawData, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, QImage::Format_Indexed8);

            _videostr->updateImage(clImage);
        }else

...
```

Image provider :

```
PipeVideoStreamPlayer::PipeVideoStreamPlayer(QQuickView* ptrApp)
: QQuickView(),
  QQuickImageProvider(QQmlImageProviderBase::Image)
{
    _ptrApp = ptrApp;
}
```

Update function :

```
void
PipeVideoStreamPlayer::updateImage(const QImage& image)
{
   _myImage = image;
    QObject* objMain = (QObject*) _ptrApp->rootObject();
    QQuickItem *obj = objMain->findChild<QQuickItem*>("videoStreamFrame");

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "reload");
}
```

In QML, image + reload function called at each frame :

```
Image {
    objectName: "videoStreamFrame"
    cache: false
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    source: "image://videostream/yellow"

    function reload() {
        var oldSource = source;
        source = "";
        source = oldSource;
    }
```

The app can run for 5 minutes before crashing, and sometimes it takes only 10 seconds.
If I comment the reload function it doesn't crash either.

EDIT:

Here are the modifications I've done so far :

```
class StreamPainter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QImage streamImage READ streamImage WRITE setStreamImage NOTIFY streamImageChanged)
public:
    StreamPainter(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~StreamPainter();

    QImage streamImage();
    void setStreamImage(QImage clImage);

signals:
    void streamImageChanged(QImage Image);

public slots:
private:
    QImage _streamImage;
};

QImage StreamPainter::streamImage()
{
    return _streamImage;
}

void StreamPainter::setStreamImage(QImage clImage)
{
    _streamImage = clImage;
    emit streamImageChanged(clImage);
}
```

Set context :

```
view->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("streamImage", streamImage);
```

In my thread :

```
QImage clImage(_rawData, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, QImage::Format_Indexed8);

_spvideostr->setStreamImage(clImage);
```

Now I need to display the image in QML but how to do it here without ImageProvider ?

Comment: What’s_ptrApp? Those lookup lines in updateImage don’t look thread-safe, as you’re accessing objects from the main UI thread from your worker thread. I’d rather send the whole QImage to the other thread, via a signal. (It’s implicitly shared, so the copying is cheap). Also, I’d export it via a Q_PROPERTY to QML and use a binding in there, instead having knowledge about QML items in the C++. Or, even better, make the movie item a custom QQuickItem painting the frames itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added the code part about _ptrApp. Sorry I'm still learning QML and I have difficulties to understand your method but I will try with those new informations.
But how to refresh the image only in QML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't managed to change really the code to display the image, I think a lot of problems are coming from how the `thread` is used in my program but for the moment I managed to fix the problem by using a `mutex` around the private `_myImage` variable in the `request` function called by QML and the `updateImage` called by the thread :

```
QImage PipeVideoStreamPlayer::requestImage(const QString & id, QSize * size, const QSize & requestedSize)
 {
    Q_UNUSED(id)
    Q_UNUSED(size)
    Q_UNUSED(requestedSize)

    _mutex.lock();
    _prevImage = _myImage;
    _mutex.unlock();
    return _prevImage;
 }
```

When `_myImage` is locked I send the previous image. Since it isn't happening a lot I should just lose some frames from time to time but it will not be visible.

```
void
PipeVideoStreamPlayer::updateImage(const QImage& image)
{
    _mutex.lock();
   _myImage = image;
   _mutex.unlock();
    QObject* objMain = (QObject*) _ptrApp->rootObject();
    QQuickItem *obj = objMain->findChild<QQuickItem*>("videoStreamFrame");

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "reload");
}
```